# how to forcefully update the mini cart count in magento 2

Tags: cart, magento-2.1, shopping-cart

Sometimes mini cart showing the wrong count. So is there any possible ways to forcefully update the mini cart count.

The customer can select one free sample item when grand total greater than **1500** otherwise no. After selecting free sample item if customer update with less than `Qty` on that time Grand total is less than **1500** I am removing the free sample item. It's removing successfully but the count is showing wrong.

**UpdatePost.php**

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Modulename]\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

class UpdatePost extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost{


    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
     */
    protected $_quoteItem;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart,
            $productRepository
        );
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_quoteItem = $item;
    }


    public function execute(){

        try{

            parent::execute();

            $grandTotal = $this->cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
            $isFreeSample = false;
            $isFreeGift = false;

            if($grandTotal == 0 || $grandTotal < 1500){

                $categoryId = $this->getFreeSampleCategoryId();
                $free_sample_productCollection = $this->getProductCollection($categoryId);

                //$cartItems = $this->cart->getItems();
                $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

                foreach($free_sample_productCollection as $_product){

                    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {

                        $_productId = (int) $item->getProductId();
                        if($_productId == $_product->getEntityId()){
                            $this->cart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
                            $isFreeSample = true;
                        }

                    }

                }

                if($isFreeSample){
                    $free_sample_text = "Successfully removed Free Sample Product";
                    $message = __($free_sample_text,'Free Sample');
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                    $isFreeSample = false;
                }

            }


        }catch (Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t update the item.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            parent::execute();
        }
        return $this->_goBack();

    }

}
```

[image]

and I tried `[Namespace]/[ModuelName]/etc/frontend/sections.xml` also no luck

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="checkout/cart/updatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Can you put more detail? Do you try section.xml for update minicart functionality?

Comment: @SohelRana see my thread is updated.

Comment: @SohelRana Any Help?

Comment: Can you delete 'sections.xml' and clear cache and try?

Comment: @SohelRana tried. no luck

Comment: I have tried 2.1.3, it's working.

Comment: @SohelRana Ok. I will back after I tried.

Comment: @SohelRana I tried  `Magento Ver 2.1.3` no luck. When adding or removing Item it's working. But when updating the `Qty` free sample will automatically removed, on that time not updating the `mini cart` **Count**.

Comment: I see, In that case need your module for checking.

Comment: @SohelRana it's a too much of code. So simply create one **category** and **product**, assign product to newly created category. come to **storefront** add one Normal product and add free gift(newly created) product. Go to cart page write some logic (as my above code) if less than **1500** amount remove the free item. now see the result. It's difficult. I think you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: @magento two can you find out solution? Also i have facing issue.

Comment: @VithalBariya see my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182356/cart-items-not-updating-properly-in-magento-2/183506#183506

Comment: @magento two I have try your post and it's work prefect, Thanks again for save my time.